# Can I test if my site's URLs have 403 errors for Google Ads Bot?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, http, error, 403-forbidden

All URLs in my WordPress site can be visited via browser such as FireFox and Chrome successfully. However, today I receive emails from Google Ads telling me that some of the URLs have errors. The error code is HTTP error:403.

So I just doubt that is it possible that some URLs can be accessed via Browser, but cannot be accessed by Google Robot? If yes, then is there a way to find or test such URLs?

My site using WordPress, there are some redirects in the URL, also I remove the category from the permalink. All these may be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I also encounter the same problem. Have you solved the problem now?